# android screen resolution

Tags: android

How to know the resolution of phone programatically in android .help me please

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);

final int height = dm.heightPixels;
final int width = dm.widthPixels;
```

But you should have used site's search before asking this question.

Comment: This is not the correct way to get the size to use in an app's UI; see my answer for the reason why.

Answer (score 1):

You should *not* be using Display.getMetrics() to get the display size.  This returns the *raw* display size, not including things like the status bar, IME, or even more important Honeycomb's always-there system bar.  The correct way to get the size you should use is by participating in the view hierarchy layout, and using the size that is given to your view when the layout happens.

Comment: True, but for some things you do want to known the full res of the device. So this is still a useful question.